# Splitting the x-axis into two groups in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a plot in matplotlib where I've applied two methods to two datasets, altering the type of fit for each one, so that I have 8 data result points.

This is the code I currently have:

```
n_groups = 4
means_type1 = (10,20,10,15)
means_type2 = (20,30,15,10)

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.grid(which='major', color='#EEEEEE', linewidth=0.5,zorder=0)
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, means_type1, bar_width,
alpha=1,
color='blue',
label='Type 1',zorder=3)

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, means_type2, bar_width,
alpha=1,
color='green',
label='Type 2',zorder=3)

plt.ylabel('Metric')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('Dataset 1', 'Dataset 2', 'Dataset 1', 'Dataset 2'))
plt.legend()
plt.figtext(0.4,0.01, "Method 1", ha="center", va="center",fontsize=7)
plt.figtext(0.77,0.01, "Method 2", ha="center", va="center",fontsize=7)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which generates the plot:

[image: Attempt]

The plot is mostly what I'm after, but there are two key changes I can't seem to make:

- The labels for the dataset aren't centered - they're centered around just Type 2. This is also the case for the x-axis tick.
- The method labels aren't centered, I've put them approximately in the middle.
- I'd like some way to separate the methods. Something like a vertical line going down from the x-axis to split it up a bit.

Comment: Maybe try `rects1 = plt.bar(index-bar_width/2, ...)` and `rects2 = plt.bar(index+bar_width/2, ...)`? And `plt.xticks(index, ('Dataset`, ..))`.

Comment: @JohanC that's fixed the ticks issue, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Tick alignment: set `align='edge'` in `bar`.
- Method label alignment: use `annotate` to place the labels with different coordinate systems for the x and y locations.  Here I use figure fraction for the y values to be consistent with what you got from `plt.figtext`, but data coordinates for the x-values.
- Vertical line: use `ax.vline`.

Note that having set `align='edge'` in `bar`, the left edges of your blue bars are at the `index` values.  So the line and "Method" annotations are 0.15 less than that in the x-direction.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n_groups = 4
means_type1 = (10,20,10,15)
means_type2 = (20,30,15,10)

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.grid(which='major', color='#EEEEEE', linewidth=0.5,zorder=0)
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, means_type1, bar_width,
alpha=1,
color='blue',
label='Type 1',zorder=3, align='edge')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, means_type2, bar_width,
alpha=1,
color='green',
label='Type 2',zorder=3, align='edge')

ax.axvline(index[2] - 0.15, color='gray', linestyle='dashed')

plt.ylabel('Metric')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('Dataset 1', 'Dataset 2', 'Dataset 1', 'Dataset 2'))
plt.legend()
ax.annotate("Method 1", (index[1] - 0.15, 0.01), xycoords=('data', 'figure fraction'), ha="center", va="center",fontsize=7)
ax.annotate("Method 2", (index[3] - 0.15, 0.01), xycoords=('data', 'figure fraction'), ha="center", va="center",fontsize=7)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to create this type of plots would be via seaborn. Seaborn works best when the data is organized as a dataframe (e.g. saved as a `csv` file).

Here is how the code could look like. Seaborn has many options to further customize the plots in a relatively intuitive way.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

means_type1 = (10, 20, 10, 15)
means_type2 = (20, 30, 15, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': ['Type1'] * len(means_type1) + ['Type2'] * len(means_type2),
                   'Dataset': ['Dataset 1', 'Dataset 2'] * 4,
                   'Method': (['Method1'] * 2 + ['Method2'] * 2) * 2,
                   'Mean': means_type1 + means_type2})
g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='bar', x="Dataset", y="Mean", hue="Type", col='Method',
                palette=['dodgerblue', 'limegreen'])

# seaborn sets the "method" as subplot title
# iterate through the subplots and set the method as x label
for name, ax in g.axes_dict.items():
    ax.set_title('')
    ax.set_xlabel(name)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn bar plot]

The dataframe would look like:

| Type | Dataset | Method | Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type1 | Dataset 1 | Method1 | 10 |
| Type1 | Dataset 2 | Method1 | 20 |
| Type1 | Dataset 1 | Method2 | 10 |
| Type1 | Dataset 2 | Method2 | 15 |
| Type2 | Dataset 1 | Method1 | 20 |
| Type2 | Dataset 2 | Method1 | 30 |
| Type2 | Dataset 1 | Method2 | 15 |
| Type2 | Dataset 2 | Method2 | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

For method datasets you could use two plots, one - on the left, the other one - on the right, both sharing the y-axis. In order to align dataset labels, you could place bars of two different types half of their width to the left and half of their width to the right. Method labels could be set as x-labels:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

means_type1_left = (10,20)
means_type1_right = (10,15)

means_type2_left = (20,30)
means_type2_right = (15,10)

n_groups_left = len(means_type1_left)
n_groups_right = len(means_type1_right)

dataset_left = (means_type1_left, means_type2_left)
dataset_right = (means_type1_right, means_type2_right)
datasets = (dataset_left, dataset_right)

# create a plot with a left and right side
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})
index_left = np.arange(n_groups_left)
index_right = np.arange(n_groups_right)
indexes = (index_left, index_right)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

for i, (index, ax, data) in enumerate(zip(indexes, axes, datasets), start=1):
    rects1 = ax.bar(index - bar_width/2, data[0], bar_width,
                   alpha=1,
                   color='blue',
                   label='Type 1',
                   zorder=3)
    rects2 = ax.bar(index + bar_width/2, data[1], bar_width,
                   alpha=1,
                   color='red',
                   label='Type 2',
                   zorder=3)
    xlabels = ('Dataset {}'.format(l + 1) for l in index)
    ax.set_xticks(index, xlabels)
    ax.set_xlabel('Method {}'.format(i), ha="center", va="center", fontsize=12)
    ax.grid(which='major', color='#EEEEEE', linewidth=0.5,zorder=0)

# y-label of the left axis
axes[0].set_ylabel('Metric')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]