# How to remove unwanted gap between bars in a grouped bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to a create a grouped bar plot using Matplotlib. This is my code to do the same:

```
label_counts = df.groupby(['labels', 'preds']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

# Calculate percentages
label_percentages = label_counts.div(label_counts.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100
label_percentages = label_percentages.loc[(label_percentages != 0).any(axis=1)]

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6), dpi=400)
colors = ['coral', 'wheat', 'y']
label_percentages.plot(kind='bar', width=0.6, figsize=(10, 6), edgecolor='black',color=colors, align='center')
plt.title('Distribution of Incorrect Predictions', fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Correct Label', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('% of incorrect predictions', fontweight='bold')
plt.legend(title='Predicted Class', title_fontsize='medium')
plt.show()
```

This gives me a graph like this:

[image]

where there is a clear gap in the center between two bars of the 'Neutral' category.

I have tried to remove it by ignoring groups with zero values, and aligning the plot to center, etc. but nothing seems to get rid of it. How do I remove that space between the bars?

Comment: Is this the correct visualization technique for your data? Have you seen confusion matrices?

Comment: Another workaround would be to stack the bars: `label_percentages.plot(kind='bar', ..., stacked=True)`

Comment: See also [how to remove empty space from bars for a specific group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862337/how-to-remove-empty-space-from-bars-for-a-specific-group-that-was-plotted-as-se), which suggest working with subplots.

Comment: The shown plot is the correct way to visualize your data. Changing the positions of subgroups for individual categories would be completely confusing.  You have 0 entries in that category and your plot should visualize that. Which it does.

Comment: You could divide groups of bars with vertical lines like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77867929/splitting-the-x-axis-into-two-groups-in-matplotlib/

Comment: Also, if you annotate each bar with a label, gaps will not look so terrible, since 0% labels in them will still represent some values. Check this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py